# Draw gridded lines inside a feature and generate random points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, vector-grid

I have several vectors containing features that originated from a 30 x 30 m raster. I want to generate a grid of lines (fishnet) in all of the features that are more than 30 x 30m. As shown in the image below:

[image: The upper right portion of the feature shows manually drawn grids]

After that, I want to generate a single point per feature that would fall inside the center of the grid.

Comment: Just thinking out loud, but could you create a 30x30m [fishnet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002q000000) basing the origin on the rasters extents. You could then use the selected features (after you identified the selection based on theirs areas) to clip the fishnet? I would assume that if the features were derived from the same raster, then the fish net and features edges should line up. Finally convert the polygon to points.

Comment: Just reading the documentation on creating a Fishnet, and this tool has the ability to generate label points in the centre of the fishnet cells. So you may only need to clip these points.

Comment: It's unclear if you want a single point inside each feature or grid cell. If feature, there isn't going to be a 'center' of the grid. You could do a centroid, which may or may not fall within the feature, or a point constrained within. Feature to Point would do this. If you want a point per grid cell, as TsvGis says the fishnet tool can create label points along with the grid.